# Battery draining fast because of Android System

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery-life

I'm on a HTC Droid DNA with 4.4.2, not rooted. My battery is going down really fast. When I look in power settings it shows that the main offender is Android System with 92% of power usage. I know that android system is a collection of apps, so how do I figure out which ones are doing this?

It's only been bad like this for the last few weeks. Before that I usually had no problem making it through the day.

**I'm hoping there is a way to find the culprit without having to guess.**
Since it may be more than one sub system at fault, and since there isn't an easy way to determine battery usage outside of controlled conditions, I don't want to have to shut off a system, wait a day to see if it *seems* like things have gotten better, and then move on to the next one, hoping to divine the correct sequence by chance, while taking normal usage into account.

I'd try Better Battery Stats, but I don't think it will work right since I'm not rooted.

Comment: turn off the location and under 'Location' in the Settings you can use 'Power savings Mode' for the GPS, and also turn off the Google Reporting and Location..

Comment: @Lucky I can do that, but when I go into location settings it shows power usage for recent location requests. I have Google App 1%, Google Services 9%, and HTC Services 1%. I'm sure going into power saving mode will help, but I am wondering if there is a way to pinpoint the real problem without just guessing.

Comment: Disabling some system apps can help your cause..disable google+ photos backup and try to disable some system apps(bloatware)..and disable app data sync in background

Answer (score 0):

mine had the same problem too. just turn off any connections. turn on airplane mode, disable location services, wifi, bluetooth, all kind of those. Reset your phone and let it be idle for a couple minutes and things should get back to normal.

Comment: What's the point in toggling the rest of the stuff if you are  ultimately going to reset the device? Makes me wonder what you meant by "Reset"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to jurasticly improve your battery life is by getting a new, more efficient phone. However, there are definitely compromises you can take to make it last longer.

One of the main killers is using 4G mobile data. Hence why turning on aeroplane mode uses like 3% an hour, so switch over to 3G when not needed, or turn off mobile data when connected to wifi (if you haven't already enabled in developer settings).

Another is location. Turn it off because chances are you won't need it most of the time.

Thirdly brightness ( obviously ). Huge killer. To see if this is the case, go into settings > Battery > 3 Dots top left > Battery Usage > Show full usage. You can then see in more detail what's draining the battery.

Another big consumer is Instagram, Snapchat. Try switching over to apps like Messenger lite or Facebook lite when possible. This uses far less mobile data and battery.

Use dark mode. Helps massively. Trust me.

Again if you're in need to message people, try use SMS if you already don't.

Or bring a powerpack, but we all know that's effort.

Comment: Thankfully I upgraded from that phone several years ago, but thanks for the answer. Hopefully it'll help someone else with the same problem.